# WebApi No type was found that matches the controller named "BlaBla" issue

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

There are 2 servers (Win 2003 Server, IIS6) in farm. Both have same code. On one WebApi requests works good, on other - error "No type was found that matches the controller named ... ". What exact configurations\installed components need to be checked\compared to fix?

Comment: And the codebases on each you've verified are the same?

Comment: What you mean codebases ?

Comment: Is the code identical on each box.

Comment: Yes, site code for sure same, this is first that was checked.